# How to launch a composer project into production?

Tags: apache, composer-php, stripe-payments, slim

I am using Stripe's subscription use case code exampe (https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/tree/main/fixed-price-subscriptions) with php-slim, and composer, and vanillajs as the front-end.

I am wondering how to start a composer project into production. By default, Stripe uses this composer.json file which has the following line:

```
  "scripts": {

    "start": "php -S 0.0.0.0:4242 index.php"

  }
```

I'm running the project on a remote server hosted in AWS, so I cannot just open the browser and go to 0.0.0.0:4242. I need it to run on the Apache server so I can access it remotely via port 80 or 443. How do I do this?

Note: Sorry for the noob question, I have been googling but I haven't been able to find the answer to this.

Comment: The app you're using is purely a demo app from Stripe. It's absolutely not how one would deploy a live/production PHP application and not something you should be using anywhere but your own local machine to test their product. The way to deploy a PHP application in production is going to be dependent to your own experience/needs so not something that can be explained on SO. You might want to read https://phptherightway.com/#servers_and_deployment to get started

Comment: Well I know that. I am not asking suggestions about what's the best way to launch something into production. I am asking what's the fastest way to try out the stripe app demo without installing a local server and testing it remotely hosted on my AWS.

Comment: The title, your question and your last comment tell us exactly the opposite. Can you please add more details.

Comment: I just need to know how to try out the demo app on a remote server. I have an apache hosted on AWS, so I need to know how to tell composer to init everything into www.{MYDOMAIN}.com/index.php so I can access it remotely instead of 0.0.0.0:4242

Comment: How is this problem related to Composer, Apache, or Stripe? Why not configure your server as written in tons of tutorials?